# Open Source GRE Data

Tags: data-request, education

I am looking for information related to test preparation for the [GRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduate_Record_Examinations).

- math questions with answers (GRE subjects)
- vocabulary tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anki is a flashcard software.
It has a large collection of shared decks, curated by the Anki community.

In particular, Anki has many decks of GRE content:

https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/GRE

That list contains a few false positive, but when you filter them out you can see that there are about 120 decks about GRE:

- 极品GRE红宝书
- Verbal Workout GRE 4th edition (The Princeton Review)
- GRE Words (with examples, antonyms and notes)
- 要你命3000（GRE核心词汇考法精析）
- 極品GRE紅寶書(繁體中文)+聲音檔
- 極品GRE紅寶書(繁體中文)
- High Frequency GRE words with Bengali Meaning
- GRE Words List
- GRE Vocabulary in Sentences
- 極品GRE紅寶書(繁體中文)+聲音檔 2014.05 新版
- 新GRE核心词汇考法精析（再要你命3000）
- GRE Vocabulary
- GRE&GMAT阅读难句
- Barron's GRE
- GRE词汇精选
- GRE词以类记
- GRE Vocabulary-High frequency words with example sentences
- GRE Tara
- GRE Wordlist
- G.GRE精选分频(剔除四六级):5星(1)+4星(13)+3星(78)+2星(1129)
- I.GRE精选分频(剔除四六级):0星(2449)
- H.GRE精选分频(剔除四六级):1星(2959)
- GRE High-Frequency Words
- GRE for sis 4
- GRE for sis 1
- GRE Words List wj
- GRE Words
- Anthony's GRE Flash Cards
- Kaplan's GRE Word Groups
- GRE Psychology Physiological Psychology
- GRE for sis 2
- GRE Vocab
- GRE for sis 3
- GRE Psychology Sensation and Perception
- GRE High Frequency
- GRE Deck 1 sept 7
- GRE for sis 7
- GRE Vocabulary
- GRE
- GRE红宝书（安卓版修改）
- GRE for sis 5
- GRE Master Word List - 5000+ Words
- GRE1
- GRE Psych Deck 9/24/2013
- WCG's GRE Words
- GREFANG
- GRE sentences part 3
- GRE Psychology Cognitive Psychology
- GRE Vocabulary 2
- math GRE
- GRE Words with Similar Meanings
- GRE Vocab
- GRE High-Frequency Vocabulary
- GRE Vocabulary
- GRE Antonyms
- Classical Mechanics - GRE
- GRE vocabulary
- GRE Red Bible - Freq 3+
- GRE Psychology Social Psychology
- GRE words
- GRE Vocab
- GRE Parts of Speech
- GRE 490 - all words mattf
- GRE Verbal 1100+Some Magazines
- Kaplan GRE 500 Vocab
- AneesHussain GRE Wordlist Vocabulary
- GRE (math verval)
- Optics and Wave Phenomena - GRE
- 1736 Words for GRE
- Electricity and Magnetism - GRE
- Barron's 799 Essential Words for the GRE
- GRE Gifty
- Kaplans GRE words
- GRE 1100
- GRE Psychology Research Design
- GRE红宝书2012
- GRE Vocabulary for Verbal Section
- Barrons GRE 4813 wordlist pron, EN, RU
- GRE Word Groups
- Princeton Review GRE Hit Parade
- High Freq GRE
- GRE May Vocab
- GRE(set1 of 300)
- GRE Roots (Graduate Record Examination Roots)
- Angela's Top 200ish Vocab for the New GRE Verbal
- GRE High Frequency Words
- GRE words (with examples)
- GRE(Set2 of 180)
- GRE words part 2
- GRE High-Frequency Words (K)
- GRE word list 1
- GRE vocabulary
- GRE- Flashcards
- GRE Vocabulary 2014
- GRE words list 800 with 300 high frequency tags
- GRE vocab 1
- GRE Psychology Learning and Ethology
- GRE Vocabulary List
- GRE words part 3
- GRE-Barron's
- GRE Psychology Developmental Psychology
- GRE Duy Anh
- GRE-Personal Practice
- GRE for sis 6
- Kaplan GRE words
- My GRE Wordlist
- Physics GRE
- GRE Literature
- GRE 3978 words with my own sentences added
- Thermodynamics and Stat Mech - GRE
- Self Input GRE Words
- Psychology GRE
- My GRE
- GRE Psychology Personality and Abnormal Psychology
- GRE红宝书带音标

Each deck is a collection of questions and answers.
Quality and focus varies from one to the other.